# Object in unity3d not returning position when assigned to public variable

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, runtime-error, variable-assignment

I'm trying to find the distance between two objects using transform.position.

Here is my code for the scripts:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Door;
public GameObject Player;

int count = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Debug.Log (Door);
    Debug.Log (Player);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Debug.Log (Door.transform.position);
    //Debug.Log (Door);
    //Debug.Log (Player);
    //float distance = Vector3.Distance (Door.transform.position, Player.transform.position);
    //Debug.Log (distance);
}
```

And here is an image showing 1) the scene and hierarchy 2) the inspector for the gameobject ive assigned the script to:

[image]

However the problem is now when i want to find the position of that object however it only returns the initial position - ie it's not updating the position of the gameObject player - how can i update the gameObject variable?

Comment: Do you see any errors in Trigger Start() method?

Comment: Your GameObject Door is not assigned to any instance of object. Start() method will not trigger a error since it will just print out NULL or something, but then you try to use Door as a instance and access the transform, the above error is thrown.

Comment: I thought i had assigned the game object door to the game object in the scene (door) - as well as the gameObject player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When I had the same error, the reason was that I had accidentally dragged the script to a wrong object in the scene view.
- This can happen if you unintentionally attach your script to more than one game object and only it initialize it in one place.

I checked your Error image, you applied for Door object right. Put the script for WALLS or PLAYER. Will solve the issue

Comment: Thanks this solves that problem - however the problem is now when i want to find the position of that object however it only returns the initial position - ie it's not updating the position of the gameObject player - do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it (it turns out player didn't actually move it was the child object unit that moved)